# ¡Como crear un hilo nuevo a través de un servicio?

Tags: android

Tengo esta activity la cual ejecuta la CLASE GPStracker, la cual devuelve la longitud y latitud en un TOAST cada vez que cambia, hasta aquí todo bien. He notado que cuando el movil cambia de coordenadas muy rapido se bloquea la APP y no me permite hacer otras funciones que tiene la APP, leyendo encontré que debo colocar la CLASE GPStracker en otro hilo a traves de un servicio.

Necesito colocar la CLASE GPStracker en un servicio o hilo diferente para que no bloque la app y siga enviando la latitud y longitud a la activity como lo hace ahora, me podrian explicar por favor como hacer eso. Soy muy novata en esto de programar, disculpen mi ignorancia

Gracias

```
public class entrada extends AppCompatActivity  {

double lat, lon;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_entrada);

    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(entrada.this,new String[] 
{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},123);

    GPStracker g = new GPStracker(getApplicationContext());
    Location l = g.getLocation();

    if (l != null){
        //double
        lat = l.getLatitude();
        //double
        lon = l.getLongitude();

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"LAT: "+lat+" \n LON: "+ lon, Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();

    }else{

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"No Latitud, no Longitud", Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();

    }

}

}
```

CLASE GPStracker

```
public class GPStracker implements LocationListener {

Context context;
public GPStracker(Context c) {
    context = c;

}


public Location getLocation() {

    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context,android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Permisson not granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return null;
    }

    LocationManager lm = (LocationManager)context.getSystemService( Context.LOCATION_SERVICE );

    boolean isGPSEnabled = lm.isProviderEnabled( LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER );

    if (isGPSEnabled) {
        lm.requestLocationUpdates( LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,3000,10,this);
        Location l = lm.getLastKnownLocation( LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER );
        return l;
    }else{
        Toast.makeText( context,"Please enable GPS",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

 }
```

Esto es lo que estoy intentando. Cree un servicio, en el servicio coloque mi CLASE GPStracker, no se si esta bien o mal, no se como enviar los valores de longitud y latitud desde el servicio, ni como recibirlos en la activity.

```
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class nuevo_hilo extends Service {

private Thread workerThread = null;
private Context thisContext=this;

public nuevo_hilo() {
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);

    if(workerThread == null || !workerThread.isAlive()){
        workerThread = new Thread(new Runnable(){
            public void run(){

         //Aqui coloque mi clase GPStracker      

                public Location getLocation() {

                    sonido = MediaPlayer.create( context,R.raw.sonido );

                    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context,android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        Toast.makeText(context, "Permisson not granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        return null;
                    }

                    LocationManager lm = (LocationManager)context.getSystemService( Context.LOCATION_SERVICE );

                    boolean isGPSEnabled = lm.isProviderEnabled( LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER );

                    if (isGPSEnabled) {
                        lm.requestLocationUpdates( LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,3000,10,this);
                        Location l = lm.getLastKnownLocation( LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER );

                        return l;

                    }else{
                        Toast.makeText( context,"Please enable GPS",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
                    }

                    return null;
                }



            }
        });
        workerThread.start();
    }
    return START_STICKY;
}


@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

   sonido = MediaPlayer.create( context,R.raw.sonido );

   Toast.makeText( context,"Cambio de Coordenadas  \n"+location.getLatitude()+"\n"+location.getLongitude()+"\n"+location.getAltitude()+"\n"+location.getSpeed(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();

}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO: Return the communication channel to the service.
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
}
```

}

Comment: Hola! Podrias agregar el error que te aparece en el Log para tener un mejor contexto del problema  :D

Comment: Hola! rguzman me mataste, no se que es Log, pase de AP2 inventor a AS hace poco tiempo, apenas estoy entendiendo los conceptos. Lo que intente hacer fue lo siguiente: cree una clase así (public class hilo_nuevo extends Service { })  luego dentro del onStartCommand he intentado crear un hilo donde colocar mi CLASE GPStracker, pero la verdad no se como, cualquier cosa (codigo) que coloco que he visto en otros ejemplos me genera error. El error no es cuando compilo y me genera el APK, sino luego de instalarlo e intentar correr la APP, no ingresa  a la APP. Gracias rguzman

Comment: No hay problema! En el siguiente link podrás observar donde podemos encontrar los logs en AS. https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/am-logcat?hl=es . Cuando ejecutas ejecutas/instalas tu app en un dispositivo, en la parte inferior de Android Studio aparece una pestaña llamada LogCat, cuando tu app muere o le pasa algo, ahi podemos observar las razones por la que esto pasó :)

Comment: Buen día, encontre event Log, LogCat no. Hay alguna forma de pegar una imagen aquí del error?, describirlo es complicado, ¿donde puedo colocar el código del servicio que estoy intentando hacer?, ¿Edito la pregunta inicial o en uno de estos comentarios.? para que veas mi problema, es mas fácil así creo yo.

Comment: Creo que podrías agregar toda la información en la misma pregunta, mientras más detalle mejor :)

Comment: Ok, voy a editar la pregunta inicial, agregando lo que he intentado hacer, gracias

Comment: Para ejecutar tareas pesadas en Android, hay varias opciones. Puedes empezar investigando por la clase Thread, AsyncTask y cómo comunicar un proceso en background con el hilo principal (Callbacks y Handler).  Por último mira y Coroutines.  Con esto ya puedes tener una idea cómo resolverlo.

Comment: Buenas tardes, alguien me puede colaborar por favor